# Actin-myosin cortex stiffness VS elasticity

Tags: cell-biology, bio-mechanics, cytoskeleton

I have two questions on the mechanics of actin-myosin network:

1- Actomyosin cortex as an elastic material is defined by its elastic modulus $E$. But I know that elasticity would be described by the stiffness of the material!

How do $E$ differ from cortex stiffness $k$ then?

2- What is the difference between passive and active mechanics? In this article, Box 1 page 3 (538), [https://www.cell.com/trends/cell-biology/fulltext/S0962-8924(12)00111-0#:~:text=The%20cortex%20is%20a%20thin,role%20in%20cell%20shape%20control.](https://www.cell.com/trends/cell-biology/fulltext/S0962-8924(12)00111-0#:%7E:text=The%20cortex%20is%20a%20thin,role%20in%20cell%20shape%20control.), they wrote in the second column "Actin networks differ from passive semiflexible polymers" but they already at the beginning said that "actin filaments are semiflexible polymers". This makes confusion for me in understanding the difference between passive and active properties in cell mechanics.